# Normalizing Nested Many To Many

Tags: javascript, normalizr

I am looking to find a way to normalize nested many to many relationships.

However, it has been going when the model is a few levels deep, such as Categories in the example below. In the output the location id `27` only contains category ids `1` and `7` (which I assume is because that is what the last version of location `27` shows). What is the best approach in normalizing this type of data?

Would using shop id in the location be a good idea? i.e.

```
"locations": {
    "1-27": {
        "id": 27,
        "label": "Birmingham",
        "categories": [
            1,
            2,
            7
        ]
    },
    "2-27": {
        "id": 27,
        "label": "Birmingham",
        "categories": [
            1,
            7
        ]
    }
},
```

Thanks for taking the time to read this!

## Additional Data Details

### Database

```
Shops
    id
    label
Locations
    id
    label
Location_Shop
    location_id
    shop_id
Categories
    id
    label
Category_Location
    category_id
    location_id
```

### Example Data

```
    [
    {
        id: 1,
        label: 'First Shop',
        locations: [
            {
                id: 27,
                label: 'Birmingham',
                categories: [
                    {
                        id: 1,
                        label: 'Car Park',
                    },
                    {
                        id: 2,
                        label: 'Petrol Station',
                    },
                    {
                        id: 7,
                        label: 'Bakery',
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        label: 'Second Shop',
        locations: [
            {
                id: 27,
                label: 'Birmingham',
                categories: [
                    {
                        id: 1,
                        label: 'Car Park',
                    },
                    {
                        id: 7,
                        label: 'Bakery',
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
]
```

### Code

```
const categorySchema = new schema.Entity('categories');
const locationSchema = new schema.Entity('locations', {
    categories: [categorySchema],
});
const shopSchema = new schema.Entity('shops', {
    locations: [locationSchema],
});
```

### Output

```
{
    "entities": {
        "categories": {
            "1": {
                "id": 1,
                "label": "Car Park"
            },
            "2": {
                "id": 2,
                "label": "Petrol Station"
            },
            "7": {
                "id": 7,
                "label": "Bakery"
            }
        },
        "locations": {
            "27": {
                "id": 27,
                "label": "Birmingham",
                "categories": [
                    1,
                    7
                ]
            }
        },
        "shops": {
            "1": {
                "id": 1,
                "label": "First Shop",
                "locations": [
                    27
                ]
            },
            "2": {
                "id": 2,
                "label": "Second Shop",
                "locations": [
                    27
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "result": [
        1,
        2
    ]
}
```